# NoMethodError in Statuses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE: Overall I am still trying to get rid of the error I am getting below.  I re-watched the videos multiple times to try to identify the step I may have went wrong.  I deleted my db/migrate AddUserIdtoStatuses and redid this.  Now when I rake db:migrate I get the following errors in my terminal:

```
new-host:treebook ScottDAlessandro$ rake db:migrate
==  AddUserIdToStatuses: migrating ============================================
-- add_column(:statuses, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "statuses" ADD "user_id" integer/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:264:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:400:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/treebook/db/migrate/20130610190852_add_user_id_to_statuses.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I see duplicate column name, does this mean when I deleted the file before to "redo" some of my most recent work on the project, that I didn't delete everything in my SQL database?

I am following a Ruby on Rails guide on teamtreehouse.com.  I keep running into this error

```
NoMethodError in Statuses#new

Showing /Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/treebook/app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined method `name' for #<Status:0x00000107254ec0>
Extracted source (around line #16):

13: 
14:   <div class="field">
15:     <%= f.label :name %><br />
16:     <%= f.text_field :name %>
17:   </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :content %><br />
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/statuses/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/ScottDAlessandro/code/treebook

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb:16:in `block in _app_views_statuses__form_html_erb__871609707240624879_2174651900'
app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_statuses__form_html_erb__871609707240624879_2174651900'
app/views/statuses/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_statuses_new_html_erb__3089828772916649988_2174583640'
app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:29:in `new'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

I get this error when I try updating a status on my page.  Here are a few other files I updated recently.

**UPDATED _form

```
<%= form_for(@status) do |f| %>
  <% if @status.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@status.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this status from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @status.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

db/migrate

```
class AddUserIdToStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :statuses, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :statuses, :user_id
    remove_column :statuses, :name
  end
end
```

Sorry for a poor description but I am lost for words on this error. I am not 100% when this error surfaced, it seemed everything was going fairly smoothly throughout the project.  Does anyone know where I could have went wrong or why I am getting this error? Thanks :)

Comment: in your _form.html.erb, you have name field not full_name..

Comment: There's a lot of repeated code - I think you need to clear up what code you actually have right now, and what error that gives you.

Comment: Thanks, just removed the older code!

Comment: @ScottD'Alessandro a lot of the answers here are pointing you in the right direction. You still have the `name` field on the form but you specifically removed it from the model using that migration you have posted..

Comment: I went back through the video tutorials and tried my best to understand what is going on here.  Prior to this step, when I went to a form where I can update my personal status, there was a name field.  This name field could be edited, so even if I was logged in under myself and wanted to post an update. I could edit my name to anything.  This step is taking that name field out and trying to associate the user login name with the status. Not just a name the user inputs in the name field.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no `full_name` field on your `statuses` table. Either you don't have any migration which adds that field, or you have one, but you haven't run it against your database.

Or, if `full_name` is supposed to be a calculated field based on the values of other fields, then you need to add a `full_name` method to your `Status` model.

Comment: you are correct.  I just edited "full_name" to "_name" and am still getting the error. I added the "full" in that section based off another example I saw on these forums. Originally it was only ":name".  I made some updates in the original post above with the original _form.html.erb file and am getting almost the same error but instead of full_name it is just :name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `form_for` some model, the fields expect the attributes of the model to be present. In this case your `status` model does not have a `full_name` attribute and hence the exception.

Comment: I added some new code above off the original file of the project (this is the _form.html.erb that is used by the instructor at this stage of the project). Additionally you are correct full_name never should have been there.  It has been changed to :name but I am still getting a very similar error.  Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having (according to line 15) is, that you have a typo and you would need to use `fulll_name`.

Comment: thanks for the help. I just edited "full_name" to "_name" and am still getting the error.  I also added the "full" in that section based off another example I saw on these forums. Originally it was only ":name"

Answer (score 0):

Your form is trying to render a `name` field for your Status model, but in your last migration you just removed that field. Is that `name` field supposed to be on the form at all? Did you accidentally remove the `name` field and need to put it back into the database?

Comment: Yes, the name field I believe is in the form.  I am looking at the project files posted by the instructor at this point in the project and eveyrthing in that file is identical.  In the video he also goes through this step and includes the :name in that section.

Comment: The name field *is* in the form. It is *not* in the model. Hence the error.